# Amazon S3 copying objects between buckets

Tags: java, encryption, amazon-s3, copy

Hi I want to copy an object from one bucket of Amazon AWS S3 to another bucket having different credentials from the first bucket. Both the buckets have different sets of encryption keys to encrypt and decrypt the objects. Is there any method of doing this other than simply downloading the object from one bucket and uploading it in another using java?

Comment: This question could be useful for you:
http://serverfault.com/questions/783773/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-transfer-files-from-aws-s3-to-s3

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do this once,

1. Go to
   https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home
2. Open the source bucket
3. Select the object you want to copy
4. Select `copy` option from `Actions` menu.
5. Open Destination bucket.
6. Go to target path, and select `paste` action from `Actions` menu.